# CSV to html table with conditional text colours

Tags: php, html, css, csv

I'm trying to convert a csv to table with following code:

```
<?PHP   
$file_handle = fopen("data/points.csv", "r"); 
while (!feof($file_handle) ) { 
$line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
echo '<tr><td>' . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>';
} 
fclose($file_handle); 
?> 
</table>
```

Now I want to add conditionality like:

```
if $line_of_text[2] <0
```

add fontawesome icon fa fa-caret-down and text should be red

```
if $line_of_text[2] >0
```

add fontawesome icon fa fa-caret-up and text should be green

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a `$style` and a `$icon` variables, determine their values from `$line_of_text[2]` value, then applying this style to the `tr`'s `td`s and adding the `$icon` content in front of the first `td` text. (`$icon` can be empty, ie if `$line_of_text[2]` equals 0) :

```
<?PHP   
$file_handle = fopen("data/points.csv", "r"); 
while (!feof($file_handle) ) { 
  $line_of_text = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
  $style = '';
  $icon = '';
  if ($line_of_text[2] < 0){
    $style = ' style="color:red;"';
    $icon = '<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i> '; //icon fa fa-caret-down
  }
  if ($line_of_text[2] > 0){
    $style = ' style="color:green;"';
    $icon = '<i class="fa fa-caret-up"></i> '; //icon fa fa-caret-down
  }
  echo '<tr><td' . $style . '>' . $icon . $line_of_text[0] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[1] . '</td><td'.$style.'>' . $line_of_text[2] . '</td><td'.$style.'>' . $line_of_text[3] . '</td><td>' . $line_of_text[4] . '</td></tr>';
} 
fclose($file_handle); 
?> 
</table>
```